# Exact matches in Elasticsearch (Facet searching)

Tags: php, elasticsearch, aggregation

I am planning to turn my search and filtering engines into Elasticsearch. By looking into a lot documentation I found that elasticsearch has the ability create facets. I made some facets into my left filter navigation sidebar and query my products and facets by filtering them using category field in elasticsearch.

But the thing is I don't know how to query back into elasticsearch for selected facets.

I used

```
'filter' => [
    'bool' => [
        'must' => [
            ['match_phrase' => [ 'Material' => 'Aluminum' ]],
            ['match_phrase' => [ 'Length' => '1/2']]
         ]
     ]
 ]
```

this code in body tag of elasticsearch php client. It actually works but I have other products that has Length 1/2-3 or 1/2-4. When I queried for 1/2, Elastic also gets 1/2-3 and 1/2-4 because '1/2-3' and '1/2-4' contains also '1/2'.

I wonder how to search and get exactly products that have 1/2 not 1/2-3 or 1/2-4 what query should I have to use exactly?

Thanks!

*Note : Facets are deprecated I know. I am using that word because I am used to it. It's now aggregations in Elasticsearch 2.3.* and I am using that version.*

Answer (score 0):

Got my solution!

Instead of match_phrase I used term method. It gets exactly what I need. It searches exact match not contained match instead of match_phrase. Match_phrase is searching exact phrase side by side.

But for term you need to create fields with not_analyzed for exact result.